# Flutter Problem :Not able to fetch image from Api

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Flutter Problem :I'm  not able to fetch image from Api which inside productImg.
I am not able to how to fetch the image from this Api,
but why this is not getting image from all given api.
I do not understand how it will be Solve.
I wan't to fetch image something like this->
imgBaseUrl +subCategory.productImg.first.imgFolder + subCategory.productImg.first.img

This is my Model

```
class ProductList {
  String productUniq;
  String productName;
  String productDescription;
  int offer;
  String offerType;
  int offerAmount;
  int price;
  int priceOffer;
  int stockQuantity;
  String currencyCountry;
  String currency;
  String currencySymbol;
  String catUniq;
  String catName;
  String subCatUniq;
  String subCatName;
  String materialUniq;
  String materialName;
  String sizeUniq;
  String sizeName;
  String colorUniq;
  String colorName;
  String colorImg;
  String colorImgFolder;
  String productImgFolder;
  String productIcon;
  String productDate;
  String productlink;
  List<ProductImg> productImg;
  int num;

  ProductList(
      {this.productUniq,
      this.productName,
      this.productDescription,
      this.offer,
      this.offerType,
      this.offerAmount,
      this.price,
      this.priceOffer,
      this.stockQuantity,
      this.currencyCountry,
      this.currency,
      this.currencySymbol,
      this.catUniq,
      this.catName,
      this.subCatUniq,
      this.subCatName,
      this.materialUniq,
      this.materialName,
      this.sizeUniq,
      this.sizeName,
      this.colorUniq,
      this.colorName,
      this.colorImg,
      this.colorImgFolder,
      this.productImgFolder,
      this.productIcon,
      this.productDate,
      this.productlink,
      this.productImg,
      this.num});

  ProductList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productUniq = json['productUniq'];
    productName = json['productName'];
    productDescription = json['productDescription'];
    offer = json['offer'];
    offerType = json['offerType'];
    offerAmount = json['offerAmount'];
    price = json['price'];
    priceOffer = json['priceOffer'];
    stockQuantity = json['StockQuantity'];
    currencyCountry = json['currencyCountry'];
    currency = json['currency'];
    currencySymbol = json['currencySymbol'];
    catUniq = json['catUniq'];
    catName = json['catName'];
    subCatUniq = json['subCatUniq'];
    subCatName = json['subCatName'];
    materialUniq = json['materialUniq'];
    materialName = json['materialName'];
    sizeUniq = json['sizeUniq'];
    sizeName = json['sizeName'];
    colorUniq = json['colorUniq'];
    colorName = json['colorName'];
    colorImg = json['colorImg'];
    colorImgFolder = json['colorImgFolder'];
    productImgFolder = json['productImgFolder'];
    productIcon = json['productIcon'];
    productDate = json['productDate'];
    productlink = json['productlink'];
    if (json['productImg'] != null) {
      productImg = new List<ProductImg>();
      json['productImg'].forEach((v) {
        productImg.add(new ProductImg.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    num = json['num'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['productUniq'] = this.productUniq;
    data['productName'] = this.productName;
    data['productDescription'] = this.productDescription;
    data['offer'] = this.offer;
    data['offerType'] = this.offerType;
    data['offerAmount'] = this.offerAmount;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['priceOffer'] = this.priceOffer;
    data['StockQuantity'] = this.stockQuantity;
    data['currencyCountry'] = this.currencyCountry;
    data['currency'] = this.currency;
    data['currencySymbol'] = this.currencySymbol;
    data['catUniq'] = this.catUniq;
    data['catName'] = this.catName;
    data['subCatUniq'] = this.subCatUniq;
    data['subCatName'] = this.subCatName;
    data['materialUniq'] = this.materialUniq;
    data['materialName'] = this.materialName;
    data['sizeUniq'] = this.sizeUniq;
    data['sizeName'] = this.sizeName;
    data['colorUniq'] = this.colorUniq;
    data['colorName'] = this.colorName;
    data['colorImg'] = this.colorImg;
    data['colorImgFolder'] = this.colorImgFolder;
    data['productImgFolder'] = this.productImgFolder;
    data['productIcon'] = this.productIcon;
    data['productDate'] = this.productDate;
    data['productlink'] = this.productlink;
    if (this.productImg != null) {
      data['productImg'] = this.productImg.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['num'] = this.num;
    return data;
  }
}

class ProductImg {
  String name;
  String description;
  String img;
  String thumbImg;
  String imgFolder;
  int num;

  ProductImg(
      {this.name,
      this.description,
      this.img,
      this.thumbImg,
      this.imgFolder,
      this.num});

  ProductImg.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    description = json['description'];
    img = json['img'];
    thumbImg = json['thumbImg'];
    imgFolder = json['imgFolder'];
    num = json['num'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['img'] = this.img;
    data['thumbImg'] = this.thumbImg;
    data['imgFolder'] = this.imgFolder;
    data['num'] = this.num;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is my DiseaseItem.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hospital/DeleteFile/network_req.dart';
import 'package:hospital/DeleteFile/subCategoryModel.dart';

import 'package:hospital/constant.dart';
import 'package:hospital/customApiVariable.dart';

class SubDiseasePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SubDiseasePageState createState() => _SubDiseasePageState();

}

class _SubDiseasePageState extends State<SubDiseasePage> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      // SizedBox(height: 15.0),
      Container(
        color: kLightGreen,

        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 390.0,
        // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.82,
        // height: 420,

        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 15, right: 20),
              child: Text(

                "Types of Fever",
                style: kTitleStyle,
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder<List<ProductList>>(

                future: NetReq.fetchTeams(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("Error ${snapshot.error}");
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {

                    return Card(
                        color: kLightGreen,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 65),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),

                        child: GridView.count(
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            primary: false,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,

                            mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                            childAspectRatio: 0.9,
                            children: snapshot.data.map((subCategory) {
                              return InkWell(
                                // onTap: () {

                                //   Navigator.push(
                                //     context,
                                //     MaterialPageRoute(
                                //         builder: (context) =>
                                //             DiseaseDetailsPage()),

                                //   );
                                // },
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(

                                      width: 80,
                                      height: 80,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        image: DecorationImage(

                                            image: NetworkImage(
                                                // "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg"

                                                imgBaseUrl +
                                                    subCategory.productImg.first
                                                        .imgFolder +                       //Here I want to fetch image
                                                    subCategory
                                                        .productImg.first.img),

                                            fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        subCategory.productName,

                                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                        maxLines: 3,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: kSubTitleStyle.copyWith(
                                            color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                    )

                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList()));
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),

                  );
                }
                // future: NetReq.fetchTeams(widget.s_id),
                ),
          ],
        ),
      )

    ]);
  }
}
```

This is my api Data

```
[
  {
    "productUniq": "60be583ee5bba",
    "productName": "Bastille Gray",
    "productDescription": "Wool Rug",
    "offer": 10,
    "offerType": "%",
    "offerAmount": 20,
    "price": 200,
    "priceOffer": 180,
    "StockQuantity": 10,
    "currencyCountry": "India",
    "currency": "Rupees",
    "currencySymbol": "Rs",
    "catUniq": "",
    "catName": "",
    "subCatUniq": "",
    "subCatName": "",
    "materialUniq": "",
    "materialName": "",
    "sizeUniq": "60a8c2b31086b",
    "sizeName": "22",
    "colorUniq": "",
    "colorName": "",
    "colorImg": "",
    "colorImgFolder": "images\/",
    "productImgFolder": "images\/",
    "productIcon": "",
    "productDate": "",
    "productlink": "detail.php?pName=Bastille Gray&pid=60be583ee5bba",
    "productImg": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "description": "",
        "img": "image-product-5-270x280.png",
        "thumbImg": "",
        "imgFolder": "images\/product\/",
        "num": 1
      }
    ],
    "num": 12
  },
  {
    "productUniq": "60be57ac69292",
    "productName": "Old World Acacia",
    "productDescription": "Wool Rug",
    "offer": 10,
    "offerType": "%",
    "offerAmount": 20,
    "price": 200,
    "priceOffer": 180,
    "StockQuantity": 10,
    "currencyCountry": "India",
    "currency": "Rupees",
    "currencySymbol": "Rs",
    "catUniq": "",
    "catName": "",
    "subCatUniq": "",
    "subCatName": "",
    "materialUniq": "",
    "materialName": "",
    "sizeUniq": "60a8c2b31086b",
    "sizeName": "22",
    "colorUniq": "",
    "colorName": "",
    "colorImg": "",
    "colorImgFolder": "images\/",
    "productImgFolder": "images\/",
    "productIcon": "",
    "productDate": "",
    "productlink": "detail.php?pName=Old World Acacia&pid=60be57ac69292",
    "productImg": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "description": "",
        "img": "image-product-1-270x280.png",
        "thumbImg": "",
        "imgFolder": "images\/product\/",
        "num": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  ]
```

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Please check this is one.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Please check this one.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make it function like FETCH data and give it to the return value of
productImg.fromJson(jsonDecode(your api response body))

AND

apply whereever you want like NetworkImage(productImg.img)